# linux rtnetlink: appropriate function of RTM_NEWQDISC is not called

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, netlink

I tried to create a new qdisk through rtnetlink sockets and followed the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) on how to do so.

My program opens a netlink socket, binds a `sockaddr_nl` to the socket and sends a message containing the rtnetlink data. I set type of the nlmsghdr to `RTM_NEWQDISC` to create a new qdisk, but after debugging the kernel, it turns out that the appropriate function (`tc_modify_qdisc`, in `net/sched/sch_api.c`) for `RTM_NEWQDISC` isn't even called. In fact, no function returned **any** error. So I suppose my message structure is wrong or incomplete. I can't figure it out by just reading the manpage. Anyone knows whats the issue here?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct data {
  struct nlmsghdr nl;
  struct tcmsg tc;
  struct rtattr rt;
};

int main() {
  int fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
  if(fd == -1) {
      printf("Error in socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return -1;
  }

  struct sockaddr_nl la;
  memset((void *)&la, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_nl));
  la.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
  la.nl_pid = getpid();

  if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&la, sizeof(la)) == -1) {
    printf("Error in bind: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  struct data d;
  memset((void *)&d, 0, sizeof(struct data));
  d.nl.nlmsg_len = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(struct tcmsg));
  d.nl.nlmsg_type = RTM_NEWQDISC;
  d.nl.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_DUMP | NLM_F_CREATE | NLM_F_ACK;
  d.nl.nlmsg_seq = 0;
  d.nl.nlmsg_pid = 0;

  d.tc.tcm_family = 0;
  d.tc.tcm_ifindex = 0;
  d.tc.tcm_handle = 0;
  d.tc.tcm_parent = 0;
  d.tc.tcm_info = 0;

  d.rt.rta_type = TCA_UNSPEC;

  struct msghdr msg;
  memset((void *)&msg, 0, sizeof(struct msghdr));
  msg.msg_name = (void *)&la;
  msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(la);

  struct iovec iov;
  memset((void *)&iov, 0, sizeof(struct iovec));
  iov.iov_base = (void *)&d.nl;
  iov.iov_len = d.nl.nlmsg_len;

  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

  if(sendmsg(fd, &msg, 0) == -1) {
    printf("Error in sendmsg: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  puts("success");
}
```

My kernel version is 5.17. Thank you in advance

Comment: `tc_modify_qdisc` is a userspace function [in the iprotue2 library][https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/main/tc/tc_qdisc.c#L47], so in order to see it being called you would need to use that library (not just send a netlink message).

Comment: @LiamKelly there is also a `tc_modify_qdisc` function in kernel space (in net/sched/sch_api.c), that should be reachable through rtnetlink sockets according to the manpage and the source. I want to know what I did wrong that this function isn't being called.

Comment: try without the `NLM_F_DUMP ` flag, that fact that your message is trying to Create and Read at the same time might be the issue.

Comment: @LiamKelly no, that doesn't work either sadly. The function is still not reached

Comment: The fastest solution is probably to modify the iproute2 `tc_modify_qdisc` to perform a unit test. Slightly modified, you can basically give that function the command line arguments you would give `tc` and get the corresponding netlink message. With that test message you can compare it to the netlink msg  you have in your code.